# Vba code to rename a sheet or show an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with many sheets. I am webscraping with numbers, and then making each sheet have the number as the name. I want to display an error if the number has already been given to a sheet. I also want the user to be able to enter a new sheetname if so, but the program keeps popping up its own error message before I can do this.

The number is in cell D10 in the worksheet.

```
          For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If Sheet.Name = Range("D10") Then
                MsgBox ("ERROR: This Acct No has already been formulated")
                NewName = InputBox("Please Rename:")
                ActiveSheet.Name = NewName
            ElseIf Sheet.Name <> Range("D10") Then
                ActiveSheet.Name = Range("D10")

            End If
            Next Sheet
```

I expect my own message to pop up, but Excel just pops its own error message.

Comment: The problem is the `ElseIf`. Think about it: as your code stands, it will attempt to create a new sheet for *every* sheet whose name is *not* `D10`'s value

Comment: Will it? At first I was going to comment back that you were correct, but isn't the elseif saying that if I don't have a sheet already named this then to name it D10?

Comment: No, the loop checks one sheet at a time. Say I have three sheets, named "1", "2" and "3" and the value in `D10` is "2". First pass Sheet "1" name <> "2", therefore it Excel attempts to name the sheet "2", but throws an error because sheet "2" already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim MyDuplicate as boolean

MyDuplicate = False

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Name = Range("D10") Then
        MsgBox ("ERROR: This Acct No has already been formulated")
        NewName = InputBox("Please Rename:")
        ActiveSheet.Name = NewName
        MyDuplicate = True
        Exit for
    End If
Next Sheet

If MyDuplicate = False then ActiveSheet.Name = Range("D10")
```

BTW, I do recommend you avoid using ActiveSheet and assign the sheet to a variable instead.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! I see the issue with the ElseIf now. Thanks again

Comment: @DavidZemens Error will happen 

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wks
            If .Name = .Range("D10") Then
                MsgBox ("ERROR: This Acct No has already been formulated")
                .Name = InputBox("Please Rename:")
            ElseIf .Name <> .Range("D10") Then
                If Trim(.Range("D10")) = "" Then
                    .Range("D10") = Replace(Replace(Now, ":", "_"), "/", "_")
                    Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#
                End If
                .Name = .Range("D10").Value
            End If
        End With
    Next wks

End Sub
```

This is some idea how to do it, avoiding the `Activate` and `Select`, as per the [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
(Ironically, I have left `Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet`)

The part `.Range("D10") = Replace(Replace(Now, ":", "_"), "/", "_")` writes the current date and time, making sure it is always a unique one, by waiting 2 seconds on the next line - `Application.Wait Now + #12:00:02 AM#`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping every sheet to check for duplicates, create a function that returns a boolean. This function will have an error if the sheet doesn't exist, and no error if the sheet does exist. We check for that error, and return `True` if sheet exists, `False` otherwise.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function SheetExists(wsName As String, Optional wb As Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
If wb Is Nothing Then
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
Else
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
End If
SheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

And then your code could be replaced with the following, which will keep calling on the `InputBox` as many times as necessary in order to prevent the user from inputting *another* invalid/duplicate entry. For this, I've combined the `MsgBox` and `InputBox` text, seems unnecessary to throw two prompts at the user when we can use the `InputBox` to both *inform* and ask for new input.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim newName as String
Set ws = ActiveSheet   ' would be better to avoid this, but OK.
newName = Range("D10").Value
While SheetExists(newName, ws.Parent)
    newName = InputBox("ERROR: This Acct No has already been formulated!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                    newName & " already exists! Enter new name:")
Wend
ws.Name = newName
```